# How can I make error dialog always stay on top

Tags: javafx-2

I am developing a `JavaFX 2.2` application where background threads may trigger an error dialog to show until its close button is pressed.
If other background threads trigger message dialogs that are not as urgent as the error, these dialogs must not be placed on top of the error dialog.

In other words, I want an error dialog that blocks everything else, and that is never hidden by other popups, or by the main window.

I have tried setting modality to `APPLICATION_MODAL` for the error dialog, and `WINDOW_MODAL` for the other, lesser dialogs, but lesser dialogs still appear above the error dialog if they are triggered while the error dialog is showing.

I am not in a position where I can use `Java 8`, so `DialogsFx` and `ControlFx` and other libraries are out of the question.

In Swing, I used to use layers a log, like `POPUP_LAYER`, `ALERT_LAYER`, `ERROR_LAYER`, but I can't find anything similar in `JavaFx`.

Regards,
Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

If your using an additional stage to show your dialogs you can use its method

```
stage.showAndWait();
```

which blocks any event till you close the stage again.
Hope that helps.